# How can Prestashop 1.5 Webservice can return json format instead of xml format

Tags: json, web-services, prestashop-1.5

I want the webservice to return JSON format instead of the default XML. What should I do?

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<customers>
<customer id="1" xlink:href="http://www.mywebsite.com/api/customers/1"/>
<customer id="2" xlink:href="http://www.mywebsite.com/api/customers/2"/>
</customers>
</prestashop>
```

This is what I am getting when I entered http://www.mywebsite.com/api/customers in the address bar. This is XML format. I need to convert this into JSON.

Comment: Could you add some specific context to your question? Even your previous research on the topic would be great.

Comment: @Alberto de Paola Please refer to the below link :                                  http://flowcoding.com/prestashop-webservice-json .                                   Here in the above link, Prestashop 1.6 version can return json format. Similarly, how can I do the same in Prestashop 1.5?. :)

Comment: I don't know Prestashop, I'm only suggesting you to improve your question. It's easier to help when you present a defined problem, what you tried, what tutorial you followed and what exception you are seeing. Have you tried the steps in that link?

Comment: @Alberto de Paola The link which I have shared with you is for prestashop version 1.6. Currently I am using Prestashop 1.5 version. I tried the above steps but unfortunately it didn't work in Prestashop 1.5 version. All I need to do is just return json format instead of the default xml format while using webservice.

Comment: I saw that, do you now if that feature is supported in version 1.5? Did you search in google for it? As I said, the idea is that you give away in your question as much detail as possible, so someone that knows the platform can help you quickly.

Comment: @Alberto de Paola I searched but it seems I could not return json format. :(. That is why I am here for help hoping someone could help me.

Comment: Please edit some of the code you have tried into the question directly, so that it is easier to see what the problem might be.

Comment: Is it not possible to return json format (webservice) in prestashop 1.5?

Answer (score 1):

It seems so late to reply this question but for others that might help.

You just need to append the param `?output_format=JSON` to force Prestashop to return JSON data instead of XML by default.

> E.g http://www.mywebsite.com/api/customers?output_format=JSON

Comment: You're right, *but* the question is about Prestashop 1.5, *and* Prestashop 1.5 **does only support XML output**, whatever "output_format" parameter you can put in your URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recurrent question. Initially Prestashop web services come with XML format. Then the JSON format was added only afterward.